# Grid content aligning to right when desired result is to align it left

Tags: html, css

[image]

On the attached screenshot, you can see that pink div is aligning to right, instead I want it to be on the left side and attached to lime column.

Here, is my code:

```css
.buildings{
  background: pink
}

.main-fs-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(279px, auto));
}
.sidebar-left{
  width: 100%;
    max-width: 279px;
    background-color: lime;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 15px;
    position: relative
}
.floor-stack-main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(279px, auto));
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.unit-detail-right{
      width: 279px;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-fs-container">
   <aside class="sidebar-left">
      <div>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga id est debitis vitae, corporis velit harum voluptates magni, doloremque eos in possimus voluptate. Distinctio possimus dolores rem a corporis, ipsum.</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe veniam consequatur culpa recusandae soluta nesciunt, odio hic cupiditate perspiciatis impedit iusto temporibus, fugit placeat nemo modi illum eos similique quam.</p>
         <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ducimus laudantium cum, quod laboriosam voluptate facere omnis obcaecati ab minima eius? Quae, dolorem temporibus dicta! Quibusdam obcaecati commodi voluptatem ea!
         </p>
      </div>
   </aside>
   <div class="floor-stack-main">
      <div class="buildings-column">
         <div class="buildings">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Contact</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                  <td>Maria Anders</td>
                  <td>Germany</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                  <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                  <td>Mexico</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div class="buildings">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Contact</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                  <td>Maria Anders</td>
                  <td>Germany</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                  <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                  <td>Mexico</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="unit-detail-right">
         <div>
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit asperiores nihil corporis delectus. Ullam unde nesciunt ratione debitis cumque iure, ad, neque aut ex incidunt natus hic consectetur perferendis quo.
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe veniam consequatur culpa recusandae soluta nesciunt, odio hic cupiditate perspiciatis impedit iusto temporibus, fugit placeat nemo modi illum eos similique quam.</p>
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ducimus laudantium cum, quod laboriosam voluptate facere omnis obcaecati ab minima eius? Quae, dolorem temporibus dicta! Quibusdam obcaecati commodi voluptatem ea!
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Basic, concept here:

Main idea:

- set lime column to 279px max width and let right column take remaining width(right column means pink + yellow)
- from this right column, let yellow take 279px widht and allow pink to take necessary remaining width
- pink should be aligned to left instead of right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweaked the css a bit. Let me know if this is what you needed.

```css
.buildings{
  background: pink
}

.main-fs-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 279px 1fr;
}
.sidebar-left{
    background-color: lime;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 15px;
    position: relative
}
.floor-stack-main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 279px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.unit-detail-right{
    background: yellow;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-fs-container">
   <aside class="sidebar-left">
      <div>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga id est debitis vitae, corporis velit harum voluptates magni, doloremque eos in possimus voluptate. Distinctio possimus dolores rem a corporis, ipsum.</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe veniam consequatur culpa recusandae soluta nesciunt, odio hic cupiditate perspiciatis impedit iusto temporibus, fugit placeat nemo modi illum eos similique quam.</p>
         <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ducimus laudantium cum, quod laboriosam voluptate facere omnis obcaecati ab minima eius? Quae, dolorem temporibus dicta! Quibusdam obcaecati commodi voluptatem ea!
         </p>
      </div>
   </aside>
   <div class="floor-stack-main">
      <div class="buildings-column">
         <div class="buildings">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Contact</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                  <td>Maria Anders</td>
                  <td>Germany</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                  <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                  <td>Mexico</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div class="buildings">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Contact</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                  <td>Maria Anders</td>
                  <td>Germany</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                  <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                  <td>Mexico</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="unit-detail-right">
         <div>
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit asperiores nihil corporis delectus. Ullam unde nesciunt ratione debitis cumque iure, ad, neque aut ex incidunt natus hic consectetur perferendis quo.
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe veniam consequatur culpa recusandae soluta nesciunt, odio hic cupiditate perspiciatis impedit iusto temporibus, fugit placeat nemo modi illum eos similique quam.</p>
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ducimus laudantium cum, quod laboriosam voluptate facere omnis obcaecati ab minima eius? Quae, dolorem temporibus dicta! Quibusdam obcaecati commodi voluptatem ea!
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.buildings {
background: pink;
}
.main-fs-container {
 display: flex;
}
.floor-stack-main {
 display: grid;
 grid-template: "c1 c2";
}
.sidebar-left {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 279px;
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.floor-stack-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(279px, auto));
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.buildings-column {
  grid-area: c1;
}
.unit-detail-right {
  grid-area: c2;
  width: 279px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

As far as I'm concerned you want this, you can use the grid in many different ways, and here is one of the best ways to use it.

I changed your grid implementation and set flex to parent

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I think this code perfectly works as you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <title>Online HTML Editor</title>
   <head>
      <style>
         .buildings-column{
         background: pink;
         }
         .main-fs-container {
         display:flex;
         height:100%;
         }
         .sidebar-left{
         max-width: 279px;
         background-color: lime;
         padding: 12px 10px 12px 15px;
         }
         .unit-detail-right{
         width: 279px;
         background: yellow;
         padding: 12px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="main-fs-container">
         <div class="buildings-column">
            <div class="buildings">
               <table>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Company</th>
                     <th>Contact</th>
                     <th>Country</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                     <td>Germany</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                     <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                     <td>Mexico</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div class="buildings">
               <table>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Company</th>
                     <th>Contact</th>
                     <th>Country</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                     <td>Germany</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                     <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                     <td>Mexico</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div class="unit-detail-right">
               <div>
                  <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit asperiores nihil corporis delectus. Ullam unde nesciunt ratione debitis cumque iure, ad, neque aut ex incidunt natus hic consectetur perferendis quo.
                  </p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe veniam consequatur culpa recusandae soluta nesciunt, odio hic cupiditate perspiciatis impedit iusto temporibus, fugit placeat nemo modi illum eos similique quam.</p>
                  <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ducimus laudantium cum, quod laboriosam voluptate facere omnis obcaecati ab minima eius? Quae, dolorem temporibus dicta! Quibusdam obcaecati commodi voluptatem ea!
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <aside class="sidebar-left">
               <div>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga id est debitis vitae, corporis velit harum voluptates magni, doloremque eos in possimus voluptate. Distinctio possimus dolores rem a corporis, ipsum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe veniam consequatur culpa recusandae soluta nesciunt, odio hic cupiditate perspiciatis impedit iusto temporibus, fugit placeat nemo modi illum eos similique quam.</p>
                  <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ducimus laudantium cum, quod laboriosam voluptate facere omnis obcaecati ab minima eius? Quae, dolorem temporibus dicta! Quibusdam obcaecati commodi voluptatem ea!
                  </p>
               </div>
            </aside>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```